# Route to another page using Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following code in my template:

```
<router-link to="/page1">Go to Page1</router-link>
```

Vue part:

```
    const Page1 = { template: '<div>Hello Page1</div>' }

    const routes = [
        { path: '/page1', component: Page1 },
    ]

    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes
    })

    var app = new Vue({

        router,

        el: '#app',

    }).$mount('#app')
```

I want the Page1 component to be a HTML page like page1.html instead of "Hello Page1". Should I have

```
<router-view> </router-view>
```

on page1.html? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question. You are using Vue Router, which integrates with Vue's way of building Single Page Applications. Yet, you want to show a normal html page instead?

Comment: How can I import another page as a component to use with Vue Router?